# Getting "RuntimeError: SSL Session wasn't initialized" error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

Currently, I am communicating with the API that uses 3-legged OAuth security.

For communication, I need access token each time. Access Token is valid for 1 year from the creation date.

I have stored it in the database (serialized object of AccessToken class).

But while making API call I am getting following error.
Here is my basic flow

**1) Get the access_token**

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new API_KEY,
  API_SECRET,
  {
  site: 'https://example.com',
  header: { Accept: 'application/nd.v3+json' },
  http_method: :get,
  request_token_url: @request_token_uri,
  access_token_url: @access_token_uri,
  authorize_url: @authorizerequest_token_uri
  }

  puts '***** Fetching request token *****'
  request_token = consumer.get_request_token({}, 'oob')
  puts "Request Token received - #{request_token.token}"
  puts
  puts 'Goto to url mentioned below to authorize. Paste the access token verifier'
  puts request_token.authorize_url

  verifier = gets.chomp
  puts
  puts
  puts '***** Fetching access token *****'
  access_token = request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: verifier)
```

**2) Store the access_token in database**

access_token_user.rb

```
  class AccessTokenUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    serialize :access_token
  end

  atu = AccessTokenUser.create(user_id: 1, access_token: access_token)
```

**3) Fetch the token and us it for calling API**

```
access_token = AccessTokenUser.find_by(user_id: 1).access_token

access_token.get('/organizations')
```

While fetching the organizations detail I am getting following error

```
RuntimeError: SSL Session wasn't initialized.
        from /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:916:in `time'
        from /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:916:in `connect'
        from /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
        from /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
        from /home/test/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1373:in `request'
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:161:in `request'
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/consumer_token.rb:25:in `request'
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:12:in `request'
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:27:in `get'
        from (irb):18
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone let me know how can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 3):

The SSL session is not being persisted once you serialize the `AccessToken` object and write it to your database. You may need to re-initialize the access token after retrieving it from the database.

Serialized columns are usually used for hashes and arrays, not entire classes. So you may want to store the `access token verifier` in the `access_token_users` table instead of the `access_token` itself, then call:

```
 verifier = AccessTokenUser.find_by(user_id: 1).verifier
 request_token = consumer.get_request_token({}, 'oob')
 access_token = request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: verifier)
 access_token.get('/organizations')
```

Comment: we can not use verifier multiple times.

Comment: tried your solution but getting the `OAuth::Unauthorized: 400 Bad Request` error.

Comment: Without seeing a full backtrace and the accompanying code, it's difficult to debug. However, now you're getting a 400 error instead of RuntimeError: SSL Session wasn't initialized, so that error is likely coming from the API you're connecting to. You should check the documentation of that API and determine why it's returning 400.